# Doubt regarding the meaning of the sentence “Er sprach mit den Medien”

Tags: phrase

I was told that “Er sprach ***mit*** den Medien” can be translate as “He spoke ***with*** the media” as well as “He spoke ***to*** the media.” The thing is, in English saying that he spoke ***to*** the media would mean that he spoke while the media was listening to him; whereas, saying that he spoke ***with*** the media would mean that he and the media were speaking to someone else.

So, I was wondering whether the correct translation of “He spoke ***to*** the media” is “Er sprach ***zu*** den Medien;” whereas, “Er sprach ***mit*** den Medien” is translate into “He spoke ***with*** the media” and translating it into “He spoke ***to*** the media” would be wrong.

Comment: I do not believe that the distinction is as strict in English as you say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### zu jemandem sprechen

This is a one-way communication:

> Die Politikerin spricht zu den Bürgern.
> <sup>The politician speaks to the citizens.</sup>

The politician gives a speech. (For example: State of the Union speech.) She stands on a podium and the people listen to her. The people do not talk to the politician and they do not ask questions.

---

### mit jemandem sprechen

This is a bidirectional communication or a discussion.

> Der Kunde spricht mit dem Auftragnehmer.
> <sup>The customer talks to the contractor.</sup>

The customer communicates his wishes to the contractor. The contractor asks for details and the customer answers these questions, then the customer asks something and the contractor answers. They talk to each other.

---

### Er sprach mit den Medien

This means, that *he* says something to the media and the media in reply say something to *him*, or they ask questions, like in a typical interview situation. It's not a one-way speech. It's a discussion or an interview.

---

### Two persons are speaking to someone else

> The President and the Chancellor speak to journalists.

- one-way speech:

  > Der Präsident und der Kanzler sprechen **zu** den Journalisten.
- interview:

  > Der Präsident und der Kanzler sprechen **mit** den Journalisten.

Comment: Congrats on 100k by the way. Off-topic, but I think it's a milestone worth noting.

Comment: @RDBury: Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

No. *Mit* means the other party was allowed to speak as well. For example, for asking questions. So it's

> Der Generaldirektor sprach **mit** den Medien.

but

> Der Generaldirektor sprach **zu** den Angestellten.